# Point Groups in Crystallography

Tags: group-theory

A point group associated with a two-fold rotation is a group consisting of rotations of I and R where R is 180 degree rotation about the axis. The international symbol (Hermann-Mauguin) for this group is 2. A point group associated with a single mirror plane consists of two operations I and m where m is the reflection in the plane. The international symbol for this group is m. In an abstract sense, both these groups are the same. But physically they are distinct. How does the group theory handle this situation?

Comment: "are the same": no. There is a word for this "isomorphic" (as groups).

Comment: For groups there is a notion of $G$-sets; $G$-sets can be isomorphic. Also there is a notion of isomorphism between actions, namely a bijection between sets along with an isomorphism between groups, all this in a compatible way.

Answer (score 0):

Given group actions of groups $G_i$ on a set $X_i$ ($i=1,2$) , an isomorphism between the actions is the date of a group isomorphism $u:G_1\to G_2$, a bijection $f:X_1\to X_2$ such that $f(gx)=u(g)f(x)$ for all $g\in G_1$ and $x\in X_1$. This makes sense in particular if $G_i$ is given as a group of permutations of $X_i$.

When $X_i$ has extra structure, such as topology, vector space structure, it can be required in addition that $f$ preserves this structure.

One confusion is due to the fact that historically, groups were often defined as permutation groups, i.e., the data of a set along with a subgroup of its group of permutations.